# how to set resolve signature in IDialogOptions using typescript in $mddialog service of angular material

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular-material, mddialog

currently the `IDialogOptions` resolve signature is

```
resolve? : ng.IPromise<any>
```

when according to the documentation it can also accept functions that return a promise so i have changed it to the following.

```js
interface IDialogOptions {
  //more options
  resolve ? : {
    [index: string]: (...any) => angular.IPromise < any > | angular.IPromise < any >
  }
}
```

but the problem is it should also be able to accept an array with strings and the last element of the array needs to be a function. Something like this

```
['dependency1', 'dependency2', (dependency1, dependency2) : angular.IPromise<any> => {
  // somecode returning a promise.
}]
```

is this possible in typescript?

[full source code of angula material typescript](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angular-material/angular-material.d.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will solve your issue, but I was having an issue with the resolve and figured this might help you or others.

instead of doing:

```
resolve: { 
  //this function returns an ng.IPromise<any>
  customers: this.service.getCustomer(42)  
}
```

which will throw and error because you only pass the function, not the call and therefore no parameters just wrap in an anon function

```
resolve: { 
  //this function returns an ng.IPromise<any>
  customers: () => this.service.getCustomer(42)
}
```

remember one line arrow functions automatically return.